# How to use a function in a controller from a common widget that is used as a child widget in Obx flutter getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, state-management

I have a UI widget that uses a common child widget with functions passed as parameters. these functions are from a controller class. Im using Obx in the parent UI widget
I'll paste what I have now.

**controller class**

```
class OController extends GetxController {
  static OController instance = Get.find();
  // ignore: unnecessary_cast
  OverviewController();

  void onSearchButtonPressed() {
    Get.toNamed(ScreenSearchDsf.routeName);
  }

  void onScanButtonPressed() {
    Get.toNamed(ScreenScan.routeName);
  }
}
```

**common child UI widget**

```
class BuildEmptyListDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function()? searchPressed;
  final Function()? urlPressed;
  const BuildEmptyListDialog({
    super.key,
    this.searchPressed,
    this.urlPressed,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
        // Obx(
        // () =>
        Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ...
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        buildDialogButton(
                          Icons.search,
                          'Search Location',
                          onPressed: searchPressed!,
                        ),
                        // controller.onSearchButtonPressed),
                        buildDialogButton(
                          Icons.link,
                          'Use Location URL',
                          onPressed: urlPressed!,
                        ),
                        // controller.onScanButtonPressed)
                      ],
                    ),
                 ... 
        ],
      ),
      // ),
    );
  }
}


Widget buildDialogButton(IconData icon, String label,
    {VoidCallback? onPressed}) {
  return Obx(
    () => Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.dark, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
      width: 260,
      height: 50,
      child: TextButton.icon(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        icon: Icon(
          icon,
          color: AppColors.white,
        ),
        ...
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**parent UI widget**

```
class OverviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  OverviewScreen({super.key});
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(OController());
    final dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
    final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
    return Obx(
      () => Container(
        child: (ForValue == null)
            ? const Center(
                child: LoadingAnimation(
                  color: AppColors.contrastMedium,
                ),
              )
            : StreamBuilder(
                stream: dbReference
                    .child(
                        '......')
                    .onValue,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData &&
                      snapshot.data != null &&
                      (snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value !=
                          null) {
                    final dsfData = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(
                        (snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value
                            as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
                    List<Obj> dItems = [];
                    dData.forEach((key, value) {
                      Obj obj = Obj(value);
                      obj = key;
                      dItems.add(obj);
                      dItems.toSet().toList();
                    });
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                      ...
                    );
                  } else {
                    // when there are no obj data to show
                    return Center(
                      child: BuildEmptyListDialog(
                        searchPressed: controller.onSearchButtonPressed,
                        urlPressed: controller.onAddDsfViaUrlPressed,
                      ),
                      // child: LoadingAnimation(
                      //   color: ...
                      // ),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to excuse this I get this error '[Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. ', im fairly new to Getx and concepts. what am I doing wrong here? can somebody help me our to refactor my code and approach ? much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent UI widget like this:

```
class OverviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  OverviewScreen({super.key});
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(OController());
    final dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
    final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
    return Container(
        child: (ForValue == null)
            ? const Center(
                child: LoadingAnimation(
                  color: AppColors.contrastMedium,
                ),
              )
            : StreamBuilder(
                stream: dbReference
                    .child(
                        '......')
                    .onValue,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData &&
                      snapshot.data != null &&
                      (snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value !=
                          null) {
                    final dsfData = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(
                        (snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value
                            as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
                    List<Obj> dItems = [];
                    dData.forEach((key, value) {
                      Obj obj = Obj(value);
                      obj = key;
                      dItems.add(obj);
                      dItems.toSet().toList();
                    });
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                      ...
                    );
                  } else {
                    // when there are no obj data to show
                    return Obx(() => Center(
                      child: BuildEmptyListDialog(
                        searchPressed: controller.onSearchButtonPressed,
                        urlPressed: controller.onAddDsfViaUrlPressed,
                      ),
                      // child: LoadingAnimation(
                      //   color: ...
                      // ),
                    ));
                  }
                },
              ),
    );
  }
}
```

There is this error when you wrap a widget that has no observable. So now normally you won't get this error anymore.